# CSS Child Combinators

Tags: html, css

I guess I am not getting css [child combinators](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#child-combinators).

I am trying to target just the first level on the `li`'s with the following:

```css
ul > li { color: green; }
```

```html
                <ul>
                    <li>Home</li>
                    <li>
                        Products
                        <ul>
                            <li>Product 1 </li>
                            <li>Product 2</li>
                            <li>Product 3</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>Contact</li>
                    <li>News</li>
                </ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5vB3h/

**NOTE:** I also tried removing the spaces between `>`, with no luck.

Comment: I have solved. see answer with most downvotes for working fiddle ;)

Answer (score 2):

You're using them fine, but all (properly marked-up) `<li>`s are children of `<ul>`s. You can specify the parent (in your jsFiddle, `body`):

```
body > ul > li
```

Or reverse the styles with the more specific case:

```css
li ul > li {
    color: black;
}
```

In the case of `color`, you need to use the second option anyways, because `color` is inherited. [Here's the updated jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/5vB3h/4/)

Comment: Please provide a jsFiddle link

Comment: I am trying to over-ride, adding more css. I can just use simple css - ie. li {} li li {}

Comment: @gutierrezalex: Go ahead; [see my other comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16845367/css-child-combinators/16845420?noredirect=1#comment24291951_16845440).

Answer (score 1):

Your rule targets the child list items of any list. What you can do is create a second rule to recolor the other sub list items. For example:

```css
ul > li {
    color: green;
}
li li {
    color:black
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/5vB3h/2/)**

Comment: This is exactly what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid that?

Comment: @gutierrezalex: That's the only way to do it, though.

Comment: What is the point of using CSS Child Combinators, then? I can just use ul li, then over ride with li li. Makes sense?

Comment: There are plenty of reason to use various CSS combinators, however in your specific case, this is one simply way to solve your issue.

Comment: @gutierrezalex: Yep. You don't need to use a child combinator. It might make your intent more clear, but that's just a matter of style.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I'll stick with adding additional CSS to over ride.

Answer (score 0):

`ul` will match *all* the `<ul>` elements. Since every `<li>` is a child of one of the `<ul>`s…

You need to be more specific about which `<ul>` you mean. Perhaps add a class to it.

Comment: Or use a child selector on the parent of the `<ul>` too, such as `div > ul > li { color: green; }`.

Answer (score 0):

`ul > li` will select all the `li` elements in your document because they are all the children of `ul` elements.

If you apply a class to the parent like `<ul class="top">`, then you can use `ul.top > li`.

Comment: and yours work does it recursive... see a fiddle of your NOT working solution http://jsfiddle.net/5vB3h/8/

Answer (score 0):

#### Add a class

```
li {color: blue;}
/* ^ added because maybe initial property is color: inherit;
     If not, someone correct me */
ul.a > li { color: red; }
```

After this, add class to `ul` like `<ul class="a" ...`

http://jsfiddle.net/5vB3h/7/

Comment: I am trying to NOT over ride with css. For that, I can just http://jsfiddle.net/5vB3h/6/

Answer (score -2):

EDIT (worked it out):

Okay so I ballsed up. Below is wrong.

```
ul:first-child > li { color: green; }
```

I found that when applying:

```
div>ul>li{color:green}
```

all lis went green... turns out that the li magically inherit the color of the li (odd behaviour as I assume the content had color:#000)

anyway... You need to explicitly set the color: to soemthing other than green to see the style working.

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/5vB3h/5/)

//html

```
<div>
    <ul>
  <li>Home</li>
  <li>
    Products
    <ul>
        <li>Product 1</li>
        <li>Product 2</li>
        <li>Product 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Contact</li>
  <li>News</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

//css

```
li {color:black} //you have to have this (or something like * {color:black} OR body/html {color:black} as li seem to automatically inherit parent li color property
div>ul>li{ color: green; } //have to have parent.
```

Comment: Do you want me to do a 'dummy' guide?

Comment: @Paul: That won't be necessary, but I think people would be happy with a correct answer.

Comment: @recursive there you go - correct answer, odd behaviour (perhaps within jsfiddle maybe not to do with inherited color attribute that needs to be explicitly declared)

Comment: thanks for creating the fiddle minitech - see updated fiddle ;) http://jsfiddle.net/5vB3h/5/

Comment: I am trying to NOT over ride, adding more CSS. For that, I can just use li {} li li {}

Comment: ... The fiddle answers your question... You had trouble using the `>` and the reason is that `color` needs to be explicitly set OR all the li inside the fist one marked with i.e. color:green INHERIT :P

Comment: @gutierrezalex see above comment

Comment: Again, I am trying to NOT add css overriding something. I can just do http://jsfiddle.net/5vB3h/6/

Comment: @gutierrezalex - Your css selector WAS working BUT you just couldn't see it. becuase you set a color on the parent li AND didnt set the color of all LIs the children of your selector INHERITED the color you set thus making you think your selector wan't working...

Comment: So, one still has to override, I guess. Thank you Paul for taking your time.

Comment: @gutierrezalex NOOOOOOOOO! doh.... look it is to do with color being inherited by child li elements nothing to do with your selector (which you do understand btw)

Comment: @gutierrezalex see this fiddle which explicitly sets the color on all elements to black http://jsfiddle.net/5vB3h/10/

Comment: @gutierrezalex Yes I did see that. You clearly do not understand what I am getting at. In short your use of 'direct descendant selector' was correct and would have stopped you having to override all the time but you don't seem to grasp it yet. Keep learning ;)